# Qt - Cannot get parent widget

Tags: c++, qt

Lets have `ClickableLabel` like this:

```
gui.h

class ClickableLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClickableLabel(Card card,const QString& text="", QWidget* parent=0);
    ~ClickableLabel();
signals:
    void clicked(const QString &text);

protected:

private:
    QSignalMapper *signalMapper;
};
```

and `gui.cpp`

```
ClickableLabel::ClickableLabel(Card card,const QString& text,QWidget* parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    QWidget *w = this->parentWidget();
    Q_ASSERT(w);
}
```

file `main.cpp`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    gui w;

    QList<QVBoxLayout*> layouts = w.findChildren<QVBoxLayout*>();
    layouts[0]->addWidget(new ClickableLabel("myLabel"));

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This app keeps breaking on the `Q_ASSERT` because the `parentWidget()` function returns `0`. Now I do not understand how its possible to access parent widget. I see that in the constructor the parent is set to `0` as default. But when I would delete this default parent, I would not be able to inherit from QLabel.

So my question is, how can I access the parent widget from ClickableLabel?

Comment: I eddited the constructor to : `explicit ClickableLabel(const QString& text="");` but still cannot get parent

Comment: You are not passing parent to the constructor, so of course there is no parent in the constructor. A parent would be set by `addWidget` - but that, of course, happens after the constructor returns.

Comment: So I can access it only after the constructor completes it`s job, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent of a `QWidget` is assigned either during construction (not your case) or when it is added to the objects tree of another widget. You'll have the parent widget *after* adding it to the layout:

```
auto label = new ClickableLabel("myLabel");
qDebug() << label->parentWidget();
layouts[0]->addWidget(label); // added here as a child of another widget
qDebug() << label->parentWidget();
```